# What is the reason for the change in Nami's Seiyuu for a short period of time (Japanese Dub)?

Tags: one-piece, voice-acting

While watching One Piece I noticed that Nami's voice sounded different coming into the Little Garden arc. When I looked up info on her character on the One Piece wiki I found that during episodes 70-78 she had a different Japanese voice actress, Wakana Yamazaki, before returning to the previous voice actress, Akemi Okamura. I can't seem to find any reason or explanation for this. Does anyone have a clue why this would be? It was all part of a canon arc too.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Nami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nami_(One_Piece))'s Wikipedia's page:

> In the Japanese version of the entire One Piece anime series, and later spin-offs, Nami has been voiced by Akemi Okamura. In 2001, Okamura temporarily left the series due to her pregnancy; Wakana Yamazaki acted as a substitute for episodes 70-78.

Comment: I was just now watching episode 70, it started out with Akemi Okamura voicing Nami but changed just before the scene where the giant dolphin sea-king appeared. At 04:20 "Okamura" makes a soft giggle and then at 04:35 it´s suddenly "Yamazaki" doing Namis voice.